# Differentiator Op-amp with a triangular wave

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, resistors, differential, frequency-response

I’m trying to create a differentiator op-amp. The input signal is a triangular wave of frequency 100Hz and amplitude 1V. The circuit I have designed features a series resistor (Rin) and capacitor. Through trial and error, I calculated Rin to be 100 but I do not understand why it has to be 100. Please can someone help?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the impedance of the capacitor at that frequency? find that and you will have your answer.

Comment: @Reroute please can you elaborate

Comment: If the frequency is know, the capacitor will have an "impedance", in this circuit you can treat that equivilent to resistance, if rf = rin+Zcin you have a gain of 1.

Comment: @Reroute if I take the magnitude squared of Rf and equate it to the magnitude squared of Rin + Zcin, I get Rin = 1928? Unless I’ve done something wrong